# Block fields in subforms in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created the following Form with a SubForm:

[image: Form with SubForm]

And I need to enable Check in " Aprove3 " and block the other fields , but only "LOCK" all or none , how can I get around ? Perhaps vba ? I remember they are SubForm inside a Form.

Changing the "Locked" to "No", changes all the fields to No
[image]

Comment: can you explain a little better please?

Comment: i want to lock all fields but unlock the Aprove3 field

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the properties 'Enabled' and 'Locked'

If you change the 'Enabled' property to 'No' for all controls you can't change the field or copy text from the fields.

If you change the 'Locked' property to 'Yes' for all controls you can't change the field but you can copy text from the fields.

Play with the settings and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: but if i put LOCKED, its all locked not one field, i want only one field unlocked.

Comment: Each control has the Locked/Enabled property... that's what I am talking about. Set all but the Aprove3 control.

Comment: its not true, changing one change all, this is my problem

Comment: Then please explain exactly what control(s) you are locking? I have tested this on a form and it only locks the controls I tell it to lock. Are you using VBA to set the lock property? If so, post your code. Are you locking INDIVIDUAL controls?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn 's solution works. When in design mode, you can select the individual fields. They all have separate properties from each other and allow you to lock/unlock them.

Comment: Look my new image, i dont know why you give me -1

Comment: @SaPires you are changing the properties of the subform, not the fields in the subform. Try opening the subform alone from the navigation pane, and go into design mode. That should allow you to select a specific field more easily. Do you see the drop down menu in the second image that says "SubFormApp?" change that to the name of one of your subform fields rather than the subform itself. Each field will have its own "Locked" property, but you aren't looking at it in the second image.